# Unable to install fbprophet package in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, facebook-prophet

While trying to install fbprophet package in windows 10 64 bit operating system machine using `pip install fbprophet`, I am facing few errors

---

```
Failed building wheel for ephem

Failed to build fbprophet ephem

    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-be8bzm_6\\ephem\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w_5d9n03\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-be8bzm_6\ephem\
```

Comment: Go to `https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/` and download `Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools`...

Comment: What part of the error you didn't understand? Have you installed Visual C++?